# Removing text from the last output

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a mp3 player for my website that is "database driven". 
However I'm up against a "small" issue when i output the data for the playlist for the mp3 player.

First off i can say it's an embedded mp3 player that uses this code to add another song to 
the playlist: `%20%7C`

**Example:** song1.mp3%20%7Csong2.mp3

So for adding songs i figured i would use mysql and php to add songs to the playlist using this code:

**Code:**

```
foreach ($stmt as $row) 
{
  $music .= "".$row['song']."%20%7C";   
}
```

Which works with the playlist, but the problem is that it adds another song with no title or sound hence the `%20%7C` at the end.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to check if it's the last output and remove `%20%7C` from it so it only list the amount of songs i have in the database?

Comment: after loop, just `$music=rtrim($music,"%20%7C");`

Comment: @Wrikken because the first entry is not in need of `%20%7C` and if i add it at the start instead, the first output is empty with no title and song and then the songs list

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thanks mate, this works! If you would put it as an answer i will accept it as soon as i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after loop, just

```
$music=rtrim($music,"%20%7C");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
foreach($stmt as $row){
  $music[] = $row['song'];   
}
$music = implode('%20%7C', $music);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the last item with `end($stmt)`.

```
if($row !== end($stmt))
{
    $music .= "".$row['song']."%20%7C";        
}
else
{
    $music .= "".$row['song'];        
}
```